# SerialPort convert VB6 settings "57600,N,8,1" to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, serial-port

I have been using the following setting for a COMM control in VB6:

```
"57600,N,8,1"
```

I know that the first argument (57600) is the baudrate, so it would be

```
MyVBNetSerialPort.BaudRate = 57600
```

But I don't really know how to convert the last 3 arguments, basically because I just don't know what exactely they represent.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- N : `MyVBNetSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None`
- 8 : `MyVBNetSerialPort.Databits = 8`
- 1 : `MyVBNetSerialPort.Stopbits = Stopbits.One`

Don't forget the Handshake property, VB6 used Handshake.RequestToSend